# using python shelf class gives encoding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I am using shelf class to do my work. But I don't know why it's not working.
This is what i am doing:

```
import shelve

file = shelve.open('data.db')
shelf = shelve.Shelf(file)

shelf['first'] = [1, 2, 3]
file.close()
shelf.close()
```

It's giving me an error saying **'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'**
By the way i am using **python 3.5**

Comment: Please provide the complete error message, not just the last line.

Comment: error message:
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shelve.py", line 125, in __setitem__
    self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)] = f.getvalue()
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the line:

```
shelf = shelve.Shelf(file)
```

Here's a working example:

```
import shelve

shelf = shelve.open('data.db')

shelf['first'] = [1, 2, 3]
shelf.close()
```

or a more pythonic way to do it:

```
import shelve

with shelve.open('data.db') as shelf:
    shelf['first'] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: previously i did this. But i wanted to use shelf class